# "Same web property ID is tracked twice." — Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

It's reported as a warning by the **Tag Assistant**, but it still bothers me.

It's on this page: https://goo.gl/Y6O4Li

And this is my `analytics.js` implementation:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');

var visited_pages = [];

visited_pages.push(document.location.pathname);

//ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<script>
function gaTrack(path) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        visited_pages.push(path);

        ga('set', { page: path });
        ga('send', 'pageview', path);
    }, 1);
}
</script>
```

It is in the `<head></head>` tag, as **Tag Assistant** wants.

I use the `gaTrack` wherever I do a `history.pushState`, for instance:

```
history.pushState(null, null, headnav.data('uri'));
gaTrack(headnav.data('uri'));
```

And it's all good, nothing is `undefined` or invalid, but still the warning gets raised in the **Tag Assistant**.

So my questions are (which may help someone in the future):

1. Is my approach wrong?
2. Is my `analytics.js` implementation and logic inside `gaTrack` function wrong?
3. Is there something I could change inside **Google Analytics** web interface which could slove my issues here?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the trigger and tag you're using in GTM?

Comment: Why are you calling GA to send pageview twice (line 27 & 990)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use google tag manager it will also include google analytics.

thus the compatible way to include google analytics is

```
  <script>
    window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = 'ga';
    window['ga'] = window['ga'] || function() {
      (window['ga'].q = window['ga'].q || []).push(arguments)
    };
    ga('require','ecommerce');
    //etc
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```